# How to separate the field content into the new created field of the attribute table in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-pro

I am new to ArcGIS Pro. I'm working with a File Database which contained different fields.

The PopupInfo field  has both cases, one is access link (URL) and another is chinese language (image below). In some cases, the URL and Chinese language join the same row but not all. In those cases, The first field values is always the URL.

What I am trying to do is that I would like to separate them.. The URL will move to the field URL, same as Chinese language. I have no ideas how to separate them without copying and pasting but it surely costs a lot of time. Does anyone know how to deal with this problem in ArcGIS?

[image]

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to give an indication of the source of this data (database, file geodatabase, shapefile,...) and an indication of how the two data values are separated in the one field.

Comment: From what I can see the PopupInfo is either a URL or a phrase in Chinese language. I assume you want the URL in the AccessLink, to do this I would select by attributes on the table where PopupInfo like 'http%' for a file geodatabase or in_memory workspase then use calculate field to copy PopupInfo into AccessLink.

Comment: I can't see any examples (in your illustration) of where both types of information are in the one field.  Are they both in the one field for some records?  Or is it always one or the other?  If both, is the URL always first?  Is there always a space character between them?  Please make this more clear.  Perhaps replace your image with an image that shows the field wider so that its content can be seen fully.

Comment: Thanks for updating the image.  However, it's still not entirely clear what the possible data formats could be.  Eg, If there is a URL in the field, is it always at the very end of the field's value?

Comment: It looks like you will have to break the string up by spaces and iterate the tokens, this will take some basic python knowledge. Do you only want the URLs or do you want your non-URL strings to go into another field?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I've already edited. In some cases, the URL and Chinese language join the same row but not all. What i am trying to do is that I would like to separate them. The URL will move to the field URL, same as Chinese language

Comment: You really need to provide some examples of first field values, and then what the second field values should be.  NB:  Update (edit) your original post to do this.  Don't just add new information to comments - it needs to be in your original post.

Comment: URLs do not contain spaces so you can do an advanced field calculation (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field-examples.htm) by splitting the text by spaces, then a URL will be one of the strings in the list, iterate over them until the token starts with 'http' then return that or return '' if the iterator gets to the end. To get the rest remove the URL from the list and then ' '.join() what's not URL in the list, but you can't do both in one calculation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. For the first time, I think after moving the URLs to another field, I will delete them in the popupinfo to get only chinese language but I'm not quite familiar with ArcGIS so I'm looking for the solution

Comment: [da.UpdateCursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) and something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839994/extracting-a-url-in-python